# RoR Tutorial - A direct test the full_title helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I am working on the RoR Tutorial chapter 5 exercises and I can't seem to figure out what text to use in place of the "FILL_IN" I've tried reading the error messages by trying to match the actual with the expected. What am I doing wrong? Also, can someone explain how the `<expected>` and `<actual>` work in this test since I don't see the words "expected" or "actual" anywhere.

[image: Instructions from the RoR Tutorial]

[image: Image of code from RoR Tutorial]

[image: My code with error message]

[image: Error message resulting from changes suggested]

```
require 'test_helper'

class ApplicationHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase
  test "full title helper" do
    assert_equal full_title,         "Kim's Cool Rails Site"
    assert_equal full_title("Help"), "Kim's Cool Rails Site | Help"
  end
end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't use screen shots or images for code and errors. We can't reuse the content to help you, making us type anything needed in by hand. They're OK if you're showing a GUI glitch.

Comment: Please re-edit your question and format the code so it's readable.

Comment: That's a lot of images; please use text for... text.

Comment: The code is readable from my view. What else can I do?

Comment: Use text, not images.

Comment: I understand that I should use text for code, which I have included. The screenshots are of the instructions and error messages. Am I still doing things incorrectly?

Comment: Kim, you're better off copying and pasting in the instructions as text rather than taking screenshots. It makes it easier for other users to eg. copy/paste bits of your question into their answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**can someone explain how the `<expected>` and `<actual>` work**

Often a term between angle brackets, like `<expected>` and `<actual>` indicates a value that needs to be replaced. In this case, it mentions:

```
assert_equal <expected>, <actual>
```

which gives a description of the parameters taken by the `assert_equal` method. We're meant to replace them with our real-life values. For example,

```
result = 1 + 1
assert_equal 2, result
```

Here we've replaced `<expected>` with `2`, and `<actual>` with `result`, to test that 1 + 1 = 2, as we expect it to.

**I can't seem to figure out what text to use in place of the "FILL_IN"**

So the relevant lines in your code are:

```
assert_equal full_title, FILL_IN
assert_equal full_title('help'), FILL_IN
```

In both lines, you should replace `FILL_IN` with whatever the result of the previous parameter is - in this case, `full_title`, and `full_title('help')`

So, if `full_title` gives "Kim's Cool Rails Site", then the first line should be:

```
assert_equal full_title, "Kim's Cool Rails Site"
```

And if `full_title('Help')` gives "Kim's Cool Rails Site | Help", then the second line should be:

```
assert_equal full_title('Help'), "Kim's Cool Rails Site | Help"
```

** UPDATES **

So the error you're getting basically says: We expected to see "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App" and instead we say "Kim's Cool Rails Site".

In the example I gave, I just used "Kim's Cool Rails Site" as an example because I didn't know the actual title of your site. You needed to replace "Kim's Cool Rails Site" with whatever the actual title of your site is (ie, whatever `full_path` returns). So, judging from the error message, the exact code you need for the first line will be:

```
assert_equal full_title, "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
```

You'll need to figure out the exact text you need for the second line yourself, but you'll basically just have to replace "Kim's Cool Rails Site | Help" with whatever you expect `full_title('Help')` to return.

Comment: You're close, and I'd strongly recommend working through it yourself at this point by reading the error message and looking at what it might be telling you about your code. Hint: "Kim's Cool Rails Site" was just a random string I guessed off the top of my head, since I didn't actually know what your full_title method would return.

However, if you don't get though it yourself, I've updated my answer with more info.

Comment: thank you so much. I was following the error messages before I submitted my question, so I followed your instructions because I could figure out what the problem was. It turns out, I was leaving out the "Help" portion or placing it in the wrong place in the string. Thank you again,

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you were after....

```
require 'test_helper'

class ApplicationHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase
  test "full title helper" do
    assert_equal full_title,          "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
    assert_equal full_title("Help"),  "Help | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  end
end
```